# Group array by StudentId and find sum of subarrays with same element

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
 [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "subject": "FUNDAMENTALS OF INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY",
        "present": "false",
        "date": "2018-03-04",
        "createdAt": "2018-03-04T14:06:18.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-03-04T14:06:18.000Z",
        "SemesterId": 1,
        "BatchId": 1,
        "StudentId": 1,
        "Student": {
            "id": 1,
            "rollnumber": 11111,
            "studentname": "LAWANNA HAUGHT",
            "dateofbirth": "1997-1-01",
            "mobilenumber": "9875449112",
            "createdAt": "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z",
            "BatchId": 1
          }
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "subject": "COMPUTER ORGANIZATION",
        "present": "true",
        "date": "2018-03-04",
        "createdAt": "2018-03-04T14:09:12.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-03-04T14:09:12.000Z",
        "SemesterId": 1,
        "BatchId": 1,
        "StudentId": 1,
        "Student": {
            "id": 1,
            "rollnumber": 11111,
            "studentname": "LAWANNA HAUGHT",
            "dateofbirth": "1997-1-01",
            "mobilenumber": "9875449112",
            "createdAt": "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z",
            "BatchId": 1
        }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "subject": "FUNDAMENTALS OF INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY",
      "present": "true",
      "date": "2018-03-04",
      "createdAt": "2018-03-04T14:06:18.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2018-03-04T14:06:18.000Z",
      "SemesterId": 1,
      "BatchId": 1,
      "StudentId": 2,
      "Student": {
          "id": 2,
          "rollnumber": 11112,
          "studentname": "KAILA HALBROOK",
          "dateofbirth": "1997-1-01",
          "mobilenumber": "9875449113",
          "createdAt": "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z",
          "updatedAt": "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z",
          "BatchId": 1
      }
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "subject": "COMPUTER ORGANIZATION",
        "present": "false",
        "date": "2018-03-04",
        "createdAt": "2018-03-04T14:09:12.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-03-04T14:09:12.000Z",
        "SemesterId": 1,
        "BatchId": 1,
        "StudentId": 2,
        "Student": {
            "id": 2,
            "rollnumber": 11112,
            "studentname": "KAILA HALBROOK",
            "dateofbirth": "1997-1-01",
            "mobilenumber": "9875449113",
            "createdAt": "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z",
            "BatchId": 1
        }
    }
]
```

This is an attendance record of one batch. 
I'm trying to transform this array to the following form.

All the records with a particular StudentId must be together with one StudentId and studentname.

```
[
    {
        "StudentId": 1,
        "studentname": "LAWANNA HAUGHT",
        "rollnumber": 11111,
        "attendance": [
          {
              "subject": "FUNDAMENTALS OF INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY",
              "present": 0,
              "absent": 1,
              "total": 1
          }, 
          {
              "subject": "COMPUTER ORGANIZATION",
              "present": 1,
              "absent": 0,
              "total": 1
          }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "StudentId": 2,
        "studentname": "KAILA HALBROOK",
        "rollnumber": 11111,
        "attendance": [
          {
              "subject": "FUNDAMENTALS OF INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY",
              "present": 1,
              "absent": 0,
              "total": 1
          }, 
          {
              "subject": "COMPUTER ORGANIZATION",
              "present": 0,
              "absent": 1,
              "total": 1
          }
        ]
    }
]
```

present is the number of rows with same StudentId and subjectname and present=true

absent is the number of rows with same StudentId and subjectname and present=false

total is the number of rows with same StudentId and subjectname.

This is the code I have written with the help of one StackOverflow answer and using underscore.js.
But it finds present, absent and total values of all, not by StudentId and subject.

```
var groups = _.groupBy(list, 'StudentId');
var result = _.map(groups, function(student){
    return {
        StudentId: student[0].StudentId,
        studentname: student[0].Student.studentname,
        rollnumber: student[0].Student.rollnumber,
        attendances: _.map(student, function(item){
            return {
              subject:item.subject,
              present: _.reduce(item, function(memo, att){
                        if(att.present=='true')
                          return memo + 1;
                        else
                          return memo;
                      }, 0),
              absent: _.reduce(item, function(memo, att){
                        if(att.present=='false')
                          return memo + 1;
                        else
                          return memo;
                      }, 0),
              total: _.reduce(item, function(memo, att){
                          return memo + 1;
                      }, 0)
            }
        })
      })
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: FoRmAt YoUr CoDe!

Comment: Use something like https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer or another tool to format this. It is really hard to read.

Comment: Sorry about that. It was my first question. I didn't quite understand how formatting works. Fixed it now.

Comment: please add what you have tried and what does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested approach by looking for strunden and later for looking for attendance.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, subject: "FUNDAMENTALS OF INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY", present: "false", date: "2018-03-04", createdAt: "2018-03-04T14:06:18.000Z", updatedAt: "2018-03-04T14:06:18.000Z", SemesterId: 1, BatchId: 1, StudentId: 1, Student: { id: 1, rollnumber: 11111, studentname: "LAWANNA HAUGHT", dateofbirth: "1997-1-01", mobilenumber: "9875449112", createdAt: "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z", updatedAt: "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z", BatchId: 1 } }, { id: 7, subject: "COMPUTER ORGANIZATION", present: "true", date: "2018-03-04", createdAt: "2018-03-04T14:09:12.000Z", updatedAt: "2018-03-04T14:09:12.000Z", SemesterId: 1, BatchId: 1, StudentId: 1, Student: { id: 1, rollnumber: 11111, studentname: "LAWANNA HAUGHT", dateofbirth: "1997-1-01", mobilenumber: "9875449112", createdAt: "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z", updatedAt: "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z", BatchId: 1 } }, { id: 2, subject: "FUNDAMENTALS OF INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY", present: "true", date: "2018-03-04", createdAt: "2018-03-04T14:06:18.000Z", updatedAt: "2018-03-04T14:06:18.000Z", SemesterId: 1, BatchId: 1, StudentId: 2, Student: { id: 2, rollnumber: 11112, studentname: "KAILA HALBROOK", dateofbirth: "1997-1-01", mobilenumber: "9875449113", createdAt: "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z", updatedAt: "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z", BatchId: 1 } }, { id: 8, subject: "COMPUTER ORGANIZATION", present: "false", date: "2018-03-04", createdAt: "2018-03-04T14:09:12.000Z", updatedAt: "2018-03-04T14:09:12.000Z", SemesterId: 1, BatchId: 1, StudentId: 2, Student: { id: 2, rollnumber: 11112, studentname: "KAILA HALBROOK", dateofbirth: "1997-1-01", mobilenumber: "9875449113", createdAt: "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z", updatedAt: "2018-03-03T14:59:01.000Z", BatchId: 1 } }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(({ subject, present, StudentId, Student: { rollnumber, studentname } }) => {
    var student = grouped.find(g => StudentId === g.StudentId),
        attendance;

    if (!student) {
        student = { StudentId, studentname, rollnumber, attendance: [] };
        grouped.push(student);
    }

    attendance = student.attendance.find(a => a.subject === subject);
    if (!attendance) {
        attendance = { subject, present: 0, absent: 0, total: 0 };
        student.attendance.push(attendance);
    }
    attendance[{ true: 'present', false: 'absent' }[present]]++;
    attendance.total++;
});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this came out a little weird.  If you are coding the backend, it may make sense to handle this on the query end.  That being said, you can use reduce to "collapse" the array into an object based on the StudentId.  In this process, you can build out the shape of what the record should look like.  I don't this is a standard way of using reduce since you are transforming an array.  That being said, I couldn't think of an easy way of using map.  The result of this operation gives us an object, we can get it back to an array using Object.values().  I don't understand the use case for present, absent, and total.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfleming/4r507sts/23/).

```
function isolateRecords(data) {
    return Object.values(data.reduce((accum, current) => {
        let attenance = {
            subject: current.subject,
            present: current.present === "true" ? 1 : 0,
            absent: current.present === "false" ? 1 : 0,
            total: 0
        };
        attenance.total = attenance.present + attenance.absent;
        if (accum[current.StudentId]) {
            accum[current.StudentId].attendance.push(attenance);
        } else {
            accum[current.StudentId] = {
            StudentId: current.StudentId,
            studentname: current.Student.studentname,
            rollnumber: current.Student.rollnumber,
            attendance: [attenance]
            }
        }
        return accum;
    }, {}));
}
isolateRecords(myOriginalArrayOfRecords);
```

Comment: Attendance.create({
        subject:req.body.subject,
        BatchId: req.body.batch_id,
        StudentId: req.body.student_id,
        SemesterId:req.body.semester_id,
        present: req.body.present,
        date: datenow
})

This is my insert query.

Comment: if a student has attended the class then he is *present*.
if not he is *absent*.
*total* is the sum of both which is how many classes have been conducted.
If you look at the query, it saves studentId,batchId, semesterId, date and *present*.     

*present* is boolean.  if true then student has attended that class. if false then student has not attended the classs.

I hope you got it now.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information.  I updated the above JSFiddle and code snippet to include present and absent.  Still thinking through the total.

Comment: Made a mistake, hold on.

Comment: Okay try that out, with your data set.